# Should I only use the W versions on the Windows API functions from now on?

Tags: c++, winapi

It seems that soon after the support for Windows XP ended, the Windows SDK guys deprecated all the A versions of the functions.

```
#pragma region Desktop Family
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_BY("WSASocketW()")
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE
_Must_inspect_result_
SOCKET
WSAAPI
WSASocketA(
    _In_ int af,
    _In_ int type,
    _In_ int protocol,
    _In_opt_ LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFOA lpProtocolInfo,
    _In_ GROUP g,
    _In_ DWORD dwFlags
    );
#endif /* WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP) */
#pragma endregion
```

Comment: They are not deprecated.  Writing C++ code and forcing the operating system to translate the strings you use before they are usable is a fairly unproductive use of the language.  It is a language meant to let you write fast code.  The A functions are only there to support code that was written 20+ years ago.  There is a lot of it still around today.  Not deprecated either :)

Comment: @HansPassant Try it with the newest Windows SDK, it tell give you a compiler warning/error, suggesting you to define a macro that disables warnings/errors on deprecated functions. Even in the Windows headers you can see them decorated as deprecated.

Comment: Don't make me guess at this please, very strong odds that you are being confused with the secure C library.  Edit your question to show us a snippet and the warnings.

Comment: @HansPassant Alright, not all A functions, but all the A functions of WinSock2.

Comment: That's got everything to do with the way the Internet has been changing.   URLs are no longer restricted to Western character sets.

Comment: @HansPassant: technically, [**URLs**](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) are still restricted to ASCII, always have been, always will be. They are slowly being replaced with [**IRIs**](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987), which natively support Unicode.  Also, DNS is still restricted to ASCII as well, but IDNA encoding now allows for Unicode hostnames in DNS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The A versions do work and will continue to work, but since the native API is unicode, those A function calls will be converted internally to W calls, so using the W calls directly is more efficient.

Comment: When you design your wrapper interfaces for Windows API functions, do you use std::strings or std::wstrings? What's the way to go in this case?

Comment: For Windows, it is best to use `std::wstring` and call `W` functions, both of which are UTF-16.  But, if you are designing your wrapper to run on multiple platforms, you have to take into account that most platforms use UTF-8 instead, so you have to decide what is best for your wrapper. It is easier to use UTF-8 everywhere and convert to/from UTF-16 when needed, at the cost of conversion overhead. Or you can use UTF-16 on Windows and UTF-8 everywhere else, at the cost of complicating your interface to gain performance and lose some portability.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've seen people on SO swear by never using the `W` or `A` versions of the WinAPIs and to rely on the auto-detected version. Is there somewhere you recommend I reference that weighs out the advantages and disadvantages for using direct vs indirect nowadays?

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck "*I've seen people on SO swear by never using the `W` or `A` versions of the WinAPIs and to rely on the auto-detected version*" - there is no such thing as an auto detected API. I assume you mean the `TCHAR` based APIs, right? They just map to the `A` or `W` APIs based on *project settings at compile time*, not on the *actual OS at runtime*. Windows is a Unicode OS, ultimately everything goes through the `W` APIs.